# As a developer, can I browse posts published through my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, analytics

I found the section below on Facebook Developer. Does Facebook provide a way for me to browse the posts by my users, or do I need to store the post ID and write my own dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depends which SDK you are using. In general, Facebook does not offer a solution on their own, and if you are using the JavaScript SDK for the postings there is no way to get to the message.

That being said, the only way to get the messages posted via the JS SDK is the following:

- The user has to authorize your app
- You have to store the access token of the user
- You have to store the Post-ID of every post so you can make an API call to get the message

Remember that those user access tokens are valid for ~2 hours only, so you have to use an extended one (up to 60 days valid). After those 60 days there is no way to read the messages anymore, so you would have to store them in your database if you need/want them later. Also keep in mind that the user can remove your app and invalidate the token.

If you are using the PHP SDK for posting (which only works for users who authorized your app), then you can just store the message value in your database because you need to get the message anyway (from a textfield, for example). **But be sure to tell the user what you will store, also why and for how long, for privacy reasons**.

Summary: The only way to do this (without getting problems with access tokens) is to let the user authorize your app, after every publish you have to use the new post id to get the message with an API call and to store it in your database. This is valid for the PHP SDK and the JS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there's no way rightnow, by which you can view the posts published through you're app. The only way you can achieve this is by storing the `post_id` for every published `post`, and create a script that will fetch the posts data, when provided with the `post_id's`

Comment: actually that is pretty pointless, as you cannot access the stream of a user without a user access token...

Comment: well since you are posting on the users wall via the app, you surely must be having the access token for that particular user, hence you can use that access token to fetch the post data

Comment: yeah, but access tokens expire, and you would have to store every single token in your database. also, it´s kind of a privacy issue if you want to browse the (personal) posts of your users.

Comment: well since the users do use the app for posting on their walls, its really not much of a privacy concern, since you have to monitor the users activity

Comment: there´s a big difference between monitoring the usage/activity and reading personal messages/comments ;)